# HTML Label to fill cell height, with some form of padding

Tags: html, css, label, css-tables

I am trying to get a label to fill a table cell whilst having some sort of padding applied to the label.

I have tried a method I found through my searches but this does not seem to work... here is my CSS:

```
tr {
    height: 1px;
}

td {
    height:100%;        
}

label {
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    display: block; 
    font-weight:bold;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:right;  
    padding: 8px 5px 8px 8px;
    margin:  1px 3px 1px 0px;     
    min-width: 120px;
    min-height:100%;    
    height:auto !important;
    height:100%;
}
```

Any help with this would be gratefully appreciated

Comment: What browser is it giving you issue in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given CSS it looks like there may be browser default padding on the table cells.

```
td {padding: 0;}
label {display: block; padding: 1em;}
```

seems to do the trick for me : http://jsfiddle.net/Fb7bS/

But a more complex table and/or inherited styles from elsewhere may add complications.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
I came over this problem long time ago. It seems that some sort of webbrowsers add a **standard**  **padding** and **margin** to tables. 
How much they add, always depends on the webbrowser.
 But to overcome this problem you should consider the method of **css reseting**. 
What's that ?
 You simply add a .css file you include in your HTML Page which setts all margins/paddings and other formations done by default to zero. With this you avoid such problems.
There goes the link for CSS Reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

Well, in older browsers, a label cannot be set as a block level element. You could try placing a div within the label and transferring the label's styles to the div, and see if that fixes your issue.

Though also for `height: 100%` to work, the element must be absolutely positioned, and the parent element relatively positioned, but in some browsers table elements like `td` can't be relatively positioned, either. Also unless the `td` is meant to fill the entire length of the screen vertically, the `height: 100%` on both elements is unnecessary anyway.

I removed some of the "unnecessary" code and changed your format a bit here, though I'm not sure exactly what you wanted, so it might turn out to not be so unnecessary and that something else was just missing: http://jsfiddle.net/mGykJ/1/

Could you see if that's more like what you had in mind? Though if you could post your HTML, that would be helpful.